# Forcing labels to not overlap in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling

Is there an expression that can be used to force labels to not overlap specifically when there are more than one label per point. I have a map that has over 1000 school names and I am printing it on a poster. Some labels overlap. I have a feeling there is an autoplacement script that would avoid the labels from colliding. I have tried the leader lines and other tools and don't like how easylabel handles the data in the map composer.

Comment: If you find one, let me know! Currently we use two fields in our database (LabelX, LabelY) and manually place school labels...

Comment: Perhaps you can modify the answer given in this post to try and achieve your goal: [Removing duplicate point labels in QGIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187609/removing-duplicate-point-labels-in-qgis)

Comment: I have found that the QGIS 2.8.1 version labels engine works ok and has an option to select around points. This feature is not in the easy label plugin and would be really useful to have the points placed around the points and avoid colliding. Then using the move label feature would be much easier.